# How to install IIS World Wide Web Publishing Service (W3SVC)?

Tags: windows, iis-7

I'm trying to start my Default Web Site in ISS7 Manager and it says I need IIS World Wide Web Publishing Service (W3SVC). I recently just got the Windows Process Activation Service (WAS) and that feature was turned on in the Server Manager. W3SVC isn't listed in the features. How can I get this?

This is running on Windows Server 2008 R2 Datacenter on a remote desktop from my Windows 7 OS.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is that you go to the *Programs and Features* control panel applet. Then click on *Turn Windows Features On and Off* and enable the assorted IIS-related features you need.

Comment: Or you could optionally use the Web Platform installer to turn on and setup the generally used defaults for IIS.

Answer (score 1):

**To install the World Wide Web Publishing Service**

- On the Start menu, select Settings, Control Panel, and then click
  Add or Remove Programs
- Click Add/Remove Windows Components.
- In the Components list, select the Application Server check box, and then
  click Details.
- Select Internet Information Services Manager, and
  then click Details.
- Select World Wide Web Service, and then select
  the check box. Click OK two times to return to the Components list,
  and then click Next.
- Click Finish when the IIS service is installed.